# What could be the pattern behind Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, design-patterns

I was wondering to which formal pattern the Provider in flutter corresponds. I've seen in the wiki that the one from Microsoft is a rename of strategy. Does this also apply to Provider from flutter?

Comment: Widget trees/components are relatively new-ish constructs (at least in terms of their use becoming widespread) in UI development (within the last 10 years or so). Flutter is almost 100% identical to ReactJS. So I look at the Provider from ReactJS Context API. I'm relatively confident this pattern didn't start with React, but I wouldn't be able to tell you where it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gang-of-Four "patterns" are mostly a collection of "this is one way to make up for issues around C++..." "and this is another way C++ is broken..."

When they enhanced the GoF book for Smalltalk, most of the "patterns" just fell out of a few lines of code, because Smalltalk was doing everything right.  (Of course, Smalltalk has its own share of patterns to learn, as does **every** language.  The book *Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns* is quite a bit different from GoF.)

I suspect whatever frameworks are being invented for Dart and Flutter again won't have a good mapping to "the GoF formal patterns".  They solve what they solve.  Provider solves specific issues regarding sharing data up and down the widget tree.  Riverpod (heir apparent to Provider) builds upon that to solve data-sharing without tying into the class system or the widget tree, as well as interesting nuanced change-notification and nesting strategies.

So, don't pigeonhole yourself into "this is an abstract factory pattern" or "that is a state pattern".  Instead, learn the native phrases and paragraphs of Dart and Flutter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I am a little disappointed that there is no clear definition. Indeed, I have been using the Provider a lot and I have to write a report on the subject (not only that). And all the information I find is about "how to use it" and not "how it works". 
I will leave the question open for a few more days and then I will surely validate your answer.

Comment: That's because the 20 patterns you studied so carefully from the GoF book apply primarily to C++, and not Dart, or Smalltalk, or Perl, or ... :)